# Insert into select - not working

Tags: php, mysql

I've a problem with my application, The records are not being copied from one table say **tableA** to another table say **tableB** using PHP & MYSQL.
The problem appears only if the primary key is **19 digit** long and starting with digit **9** and works fine for all other primary keys.
There is no error reported, the process simply fails to copy the results.

I use the following query to copy the records -

```
INSERT into tableB (select * from tableA where primary_key_id=id)
```

Queries are working fine when executed manually using **Toad / phpmyadmin**.

Any ideas or suggestions to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: with 19 digits i expect that it is just running out of it's datatype.

can you show us some of the surrounding PHP.

Comment: We need to have som code to give you more feedback. How is id assigned in your code for example? How is the actual query executed?

Comment: What type is the primary key? (and length). Is tableB empty when trying to do the query?

Comment: sorry my apologies it is INSERT.

Comment: primary key id - datatype type is bigint(20) unsigned.No tableB is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have exactly located the problem.. it is an integer overflow in php.

When PHP encounters a number that is getting too large to store in a long, it will put it in a float. and when it echoes that float it will use the float notation.

And coincidentally it is a 19 digit number starting with a 9 where it starts to go wrong.

```
$large_number = 9223372036854775807;
var_dump($large_number);                     // int(9223372036854775807)

$large_number = 9223372036854775808;
var_dump($large_number);                     // float(9.2233720368548E+18)
```

So you should keep the primary key as a string or use a number formatter to output it.

source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer..In my PHP page all primary ids are created / used as strings.However in more detail my sql query is like this $p_id is from request variable, i.e., $p_id = $_REQUEST['p_id'];

$sql = "insert into tableB (select * from tableA where primary_key_id='".$p_id ."')"; Please suggest, I wonder if I need to cast the $p_id variable as string ?

Comment: I would try to vardump the p_id. See what it shows. If it shows the float format that is the problem and you should do a format on it. If it shows ok (your code would say it will, then the problem is that it runs out of the datatype on the database side (see mvp answer)

Answer (score 1):

For `INSERT ... SELECT` to work, you either must provide list of columns for `INSERT`, or have `SELECT` output match exactly `tableB` definition.

If `tableB` definition is exactly the same as `tableA`, your query should work (using `INSERT`, not `INSET`). You can also create `tableB` at once using this:

```
CREATE TABLE tableB AS SELECT * FROM tableA ...
```

If your `tableA` and `tableB` are indeed the same structure, one of the reasons why your `INSERT` with 19-digit long primary key may fail is because you might be trying to insert duplicate keys from `tableA` into `tableB`: your `INSERT` copies everything, including primary key value.

**UPDATE**: According to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html), maximum BIGINT value is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` - 19 digits, max value starts with `9`. This sounds suspiciously close to your description of the problem. I believe that you are simply running out of maximum allowable value for `BIGINT`, and fact that you want `BIGINT(20)` is not going to help you.

Comment: There are no duplicate key errors, yes it copies every thing including primary key .

Comment: @KLH: answer updated - I think you are running out of BIGINT_MAX.

Comment: well, I am using bigint(20) unsigned -  maxvalue is 18446744073709551615.

Answer (score 0):

Try in the following way:

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1 )
SELECT  col1
FROM    table2
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean

```
 INSERT
```

and not

```
INSET
```

here how you can do it

```
insert into table_name (column1, column2) values (select column3, column4 from table2 where ...)
```